# Javascript reduce always returning 2

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate a sum of the rowspans of elements in a certain class and for some reason I am always getting '2' regardless of how many elements are in the array. I am very new to JavaScript so I apologize if this is something obvious;

Here is my code:

```
let totalRowspan = $('td[group_id="'+$(td).attr('group_id')+'"]')
.toArray()
.reduce((td1, td2) => {
        let rowspan1 = isNaN(parseInt($(td1).attr('rowspan'))) ? 1 : parseInt($(td1).attr('rowspan'));
        let rowspan2 = isNaN(parseInt($(td2).attr('rowspan'))) ? 1 : parseInt($(td2).attr('rowspan'));
        return rowspan1 + rowspan2;
       });
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: The problem may be the way you use reduce is wrong, could you provide html code so that I can help make a working version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) correctly.

Those parameters don't correspond to two array elements. They are `accumulator` and `currentValue` respectively.

You aren't passing an `initialValue` to the `reduce()` method. So first element in the array will be used as initial value.

**MDN documentation on `initialValue`:**

> `initialValue` is value to use as the first argument to the first call
>   of the callback. If no `initialValue` is supplied, the first element
>   in the array will be used and skipped.

So in your code, on first call of the callback, `td1` holds the HTML `<td>` element which is not a number but a string. Notice that this first array element didn't go through the `NaN` check, and won't have the value `1` as it is skipped.

`td2` will be second array element and will have the value at the element or `1`. Anyway, the return value `rowspan1 + rowspan2` will be a string as `rowspan1` is a string. On second call of the callback, this return value will be `td1` and is not a number, so `NaN` check will make `rowspan1` to be `1`. `td2` will have appropriate number value and further calls will return only number values.

Couldn't say why you are only getting `2` without looking at those array elements. But notice how the first array element isn't added to the total and thereby giving wrong output.

To get the correct output, you could do something as shown below.

```
let totalRowspan = $('td[group_id="'+$(td).attr('group_id')+'"]')
.toArray()
.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let rowspan = isNaN(parseInt($(curr).attr('rowspan'))) ? 1 : parseInt($(curr).attr('rowspan'));

  return acc + rowspan;
}, 0); // Passing 0 as initial value.
```